# Is there a way to use a column header in a database as a variable in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'll preface this saying I'm pretty new to python.

I have a database and need to access it using Python and SQLite. That's the easy part. I have created the table and column names etc, such as:

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE Tanks \
(ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,\
...
DIR_Radius INT NOT NULL,\
DIR_Dish1 INT NOT NULL,\
DIR_Dish2 INT NOT NULL,\
DIR_Length INT NOT NULL,\
```

And so on. So what I want to do is use the column header as a variable, i.e.

```
Dish1 = 'DIR_Dish1'
```

But as you may know in python that just assigns the string value to the variable name.

Saying

```
Dir_Dish1 > 0.001
```

Doesn't work either

```
def Dish_Vol():
if (Dish > 0.0001):
    int1 = math.pi * Dish,
    ...
```

I am trying to check that the value in the comlumn DIR_Dish1 has a integer value greater than 0.001, so that I can go ahead and perform some calculation. How do I go about using a variable as such?

Comment: You've created the table, but have you populated it? Have you selected from it? Your question confuses me; I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Yeah there's data in the table, I'm trying to check the value in a certain column; DIR_Dish1. Just assume there's only one row. So if the value in DIR_Dish1 is > 0.001 then the program runs through the function. I want to know how to check the value of that column, and can i assign the column a variable to use throughout the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have run a SQL read on your table and iterate through the table:

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT DIR_Radius from Tanks"):
    if row[0]>0.0001:
        int1 = math.pi * row[0]
        ...
```

If you are trying to do some operations in the table and then modify an existing column or create a new column based on the operations you apply, you're better off using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). Pandas will allow you to create a data frame object from the query, do some processing (e.g. creating new columns or modifying existing columns), and then write the data frame object back into the SQL environment using [to_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Comment: May be faster: `SELECT DIR_Radius FROM Tanks WHERE Dir_Radius > 0.0001`. Then you can remove the `if` statement from Python code.